# Is there any way to resolve cyclic dependency like this

Tags: c++, oop, linker-errors, cyclic-dependency

I'm writing a C compiler and I am on a stage of syntax analyzing. I've got a hierarchy of syntax tree nodes. I want to refactor code but I can't resolve dependencies like this.

For example, here is a header with all predeclared classes and and abstract Node class:

```
#ifndef TINY_C_COMPILER_NODE_H
#define TINY_C_COMPILER_NODE_H

#include "../token.h"
#include <ostream>

class PostfixExprNode;
class IdNode;
class ConstNode;
class StringLiteralNode;
class FloatConstNode;
class IntConstNode;
class PostfixIncrementNode;
class PostfixDecrementNode;
class StructureOrUnionMemberAccessNode;
class StructureOrUnionMemberAccessByPointerNode;
class ArrayAccess;

class Node
{
public:
    virtual void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) = 0;
};

#endif //TINY_C_COMPILER_NODE_H
```

primary_expr.h:

```
#ifndef TINY_C_COMPILER_PRIMARY_EXPR_H
#define TINY_C_COMPILER_PRIMARY_EXPR_H

#include "node.h"

// primary-expr ::= id | constant | string-literal | (expr)

class PrimaryExprNode: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override = 0;
};

class IdNode: public PrimaryExprNode
{
public:
    explicit IdNode(Token *token);
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
private:
    Token *token;
};

class ConstNode: public PrimaryExprNode
{
public:
    explicit ConstNode(Token *token): token(token) {}
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override = 0;
protected:
    Token *token;
};

class IntConstNode: public ConstNode
{
public:
    explicit IntConstNode(Token *token);
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
};

class FloatConstNode: public ConstNode
{
public:
    explicit FloatConstNode(Token *token);
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
};

class StringLiteralNode: public PrimaryExprNode
{
public:
    explicit StringLiteralNode(Token *token);
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
private:
    Token *token;
};


#endif //TINY_C_COMPILER_PRIMARY_EXPR_H
```

postfix_expr.h:

```
#ifndef TINY_C_COMPILER_POSTFIX_EXPR_H
#define TINY_C_COMPILER_POSTFIX_EXPR_H

#include "node.h"

//
//postfix-expr ::= primary-expr | postfix-expr [expr] | postfix-expr (`argument-expr-list)
//                | postfix-expr . id | postfix-expr -> id | postfix-expr ++ | postfix-expr --
//                | (type-name) {initializer-list} | (type-name) {initializer-list, }

class PostfixExprNode: public Node
{
public:
    virtual void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) = 0;
};

class PostfixIncrementNode: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    explicit PostfixIncrementNode(PostfixExprNode *node): node(node) {}
    virtual void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth);
private:
    PostfixExprNode *node;
};

class PostfixDecrementNode: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    explicit PostfixDecrementNode(PostfixExprNode *node): node(node) {}
    virtual void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth);
private:
    PostfixExprNode *node;
};


class StructureOrUnionMemberAccessNode: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    StructureOrUnionMemberAccessNode(PostfixExprNode *structureOrUnion, IdNode *member): member(member),
                                                                                         structureOrUnion(structureOrUnion) {}

    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
private:
    PostfixExprNode *structureOrUnion;
    IdNode *member;
};

class StructureOrUnionMemberAccessByPointerNode: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    StructureOrUnionMemberAccessByPointerNode(PostfixExprNode *structureOrUnion, IdNode *member): member(member),
                                                                                                  structureOrUnion(structureOrUnion) {}

    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
private:
    PostfixExprNode *structureOrUnion;
    IdNode *member;
};

class ArrayAccess: public PostfixExprNode
{
public:
    ArrayAccess(PostfixExprNode *left, PostfixExprNode *inBrackets): left(left), inBrackets(inBrackets) {}
    void Print(std::ostream &os, int depth) override;
private:
    PostfixExprNode *left, *inBrackets;
};

#endif //TINY_C_COMPILER_POSTFIX_EXPR_H
```

The problem is that PrimaryExprNode and it's inheritors need full declaration of PostfixExprNode, so primary_expr.h needs to be included. On the other hand, StructureOrUnionMemberAccessNode needs information about IdNode in Print function. So is there any way to resolve this issue? Or I just have to keep everything in one header?

Comment: This question is  confusing.  You mention a type called "PrimaryExpr" but nowhere above do I see it even declared.  You say PrimaryExprNode needs it so should you include "primary_expr.h" but PrimaryExprNode itself is declared in primary_expr.h.

Comment: @Joe, my bad. Editted.

Comment: Why can't you have StructureOrUnionMemberAccessNode in a separate header which would include it's dependencies only without forcing those to include each other? But ultimately, yes, you can either put everything into a single header and have all mess in one file or put every class declaration into a separate headers and have lot's of headers.

Comment: OK, it's a little clearer now, but I don't see how PrimaryExprNode needs any reference to PostFixExprNode.  Do you need to pass a PostFixExprNode into a member function of PrimaryExprNode?  If so, just forward-declare PostFixExprNode at the top of the headerfile and have the member functions of PrimaryExprNode take either pointers or references to PostFixExprNode objects.  As long as you actually implement those member functions in a separate .CPP file that (by that point) knows the full definition of PostFixExprNode) everything should work

Comment: @Joe, cuz StructOrUnionMemberAccess has IdNode * as it's member.

Comment: Cyclic dependencies between classes/header files might be solved this way: No cyclic dependencies in headers (use forward declarations of classes instead). Include all the resp. headers in the C++ files instead where necessary. Hence, you may use in header only incomplete types (e.g. prevent inline functions which require full types). Btw. this works fine for classes but breaks for class templates. (Templates with cyclic dependencies drove me crazy last time until I got it solved _somehow_.)